# How to replace ' with empty string in Java

Tags: java, replace, quotes

How can I replace single quote ' with empty string in Java. I tried following but doesn't seem to be working.

```
String data="Sid's den";
data.replace("'", "");
data.replaceAll("'", "");
```

Thanks in advance. Any help is much appreciated.(Output should be: Sids den)

Thanks guys for your responses. I guess I should have been more clear about my question. Basically I am getting special characters from the table and with what value we have to replace that also from the same table. Here is snippet of the code:

```
query = "select spl_char, replace_with from entcon_splchars";
ptsmt = DBConnector.sqlConnection.prepareStatement(query);
rs = ptsmt.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
        if(data.contains(rs.getString("spl_char"))){
          data = data.replace(rs.getString("spl_char"),rs.getString("replace_with"));
            }
         }
```

so whenevr in the data we have special character ' then I am facing nullpointer exception. Please suggest how to go ahead with this?

Comment: Read the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)). `data.replace("'", "")` would return the new `String` (not change the current), which is stated in doc: "Returns: The resulting string"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable so you'll receive a new instance. Try

```
 data = data.replace("'", "");
```

---

#### Your Edit

Check the return values of `getString()` - you could get your `NPE` because your database table contains `null` values in one of the columns `spl_char` or `replace_with`.

Answer (score 7):

Use `replace`, no need for regex.

Remember that `String`s are immutable, so you need to assign `data.replace("'", "");` to a variable.

For instance: `data = data.replace("'", "");`

Answer (score 3):

I can see your problem, If you need to replace it you need to replace it and also need to assign it back to the variable. Solution should be,

```
        String data="Sid's den";

        data = data.replaceAll("'", "");

        System.out.println(data);
```

Because String is immutable in java. But StringBuffer and StringBuilder is mutable in java.

[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

[StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)

[StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
"foo'bar'buz".replace("'", "")
```

Output:

```
"foobarbuz"
```

In your case:

```
String data = "Sid's den";
String output = data.replace("'", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
data = data.replace ("'", "") ;
```

OR

```
data = data.replaceAll("'", "") ;
```

You would need to assign the replaced string to a variable.